# Bucle infinito de inicio de sesión Admin en Prestashop 1.7 backoffice

Tags: php, prestashop, sesiones

**Hola a todos**
tengo tengo un problema con la prestashop, al momento de querer realizar una acción en el backoffice (dar de alta productos, ver módulos, querer modificar algo) la sesión se cierra y tengo que volver a acceder con el con el correo y la contraseña, he estado buscando alguna solución pero no he encontrado el fallo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando inicio sesión carga el backoffice pero si quiero hacer algo se cierra y tengo que volver a iniciar sesión alguien ha tenido y solucionado este erro?

Comment: Mira el error.log del server, ahí está el problema, casi seguro.

Comment: Utiliza el modo debug en el back-end para ver que puede estar fallando. Por otro lado además limpia caché de navegador y activa lo de mantener sesión activa al loguearte.

Answer (score 1):

Mira en **parámetros avanzados >> administración**, el tiempo de vida de las cookies.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]